# How to count or show number change with a delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to count from 0 to 9 on an iOS device, but I always only see number 9. I put a timer to slow down and display each number for five seconds but it doesn't work. I just see number 9. How can I see the numbers in order (0,1,2,3,..)?

Can anyone help me with this problem pls?

```
- (IBAction)btnStart:(id)sender {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        int64_t delayInSeconds = 5;

        dispatch_time_t popTime = 
            dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            _lbCounter.text =myNewString;
        });        
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply change `delayInSeconds` to `i * 5`.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating 10 dispatches and they'll all fire after 5 seconds, on the main queue which happens in a blink of an eye.

You'd best use an `NSTimer`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
// Fire `incrementLabel` every 5 seconds infinitely (repeats: YES)
self.currentTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(incrementLabel:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
...
}

- (void)incrementLabel {
   self.currentCounter++;
   if (self.currentCounter == 10) {
     [self.currentTimer invalidate]
     return;
   }

    _lbCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.currentCounter];

}
```

I wrote this head out of my head and did not compile it, but it should look more or less like this.